# jQuery Pagination: Don't want page to go back to page 1 on refresh

Tags: jquery, pagination

I did a little code for jQuery pagination.

When the page link, is clicked, an AJAX request is set and `GET` method is used to retrieve the information from the database And then, the results are displayed on the new page.

The code is very simple:

```
function getContentItems(tableSelect , pageNumber){
$('.slideImg').attr('src','ajaxload.gif');
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:'getDataPages.php',
    data:"pageNumber="+pageNumber+"&tableSelect="+tableSelect,
    dataType:"json",
    cache:true,
    success: function(result){
        var phpresultArray = result;  //Show the retrieved result here with 
                                       //cool  jQuery effects ;)



        }
    }
})
}
```

My problem: Suppose, the user is viewing page no `20`, and he clicks on some link on that page. Now if he presses `BACK` button on browser, he will be redirected to page `1`. How to prevent that. I want the user to be back on the same page.

Comment: save the page in a cookie ?

Comment: or save the page as a query string or a hash

Comment: ok, I will search about these things. Thanks for your replies guys.

Comment: @maazza Could you tell me please where to create the cookie ?

Comment: add the cookie where you show the page (the ajax callback)

Answer (score 1):

**Alternate One**
use hash tags.. like if the user is on page one then `pagename#1`, if on page two then `pagename#2`..

**Alternate Two**
use [Web Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Also have a look on [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) this might help you

Comment: that's fine. But how will I retrieve the information. retroeve in the sense that when user presses BACK or REFRESH button, will the code again fetch the results from database. BAsically, what I want to ask is where should I put these hash tags

Comment: Talking about hashtags.. When the user clicks on the link for the second page make the url something like `pagename#2` for this the link can be like `<a href="#2"></a>`... on clicking this link the url would get changed and you can call your ajax..

Comment: but this way the page will interact with the server, everytime, its refreshes. Right?

Comment: @NavneetSaini nop it doesn't... anytime you can travel i.e move on the same page using `#` **hashtags** they don't send request to servers..

Comment: Is their any other way? the way I have written the code, hashtags wll not work

Comment: Well than [this history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/) is your final hope...